# Can i make custom UITabBarController with custom event tap on TabBarItem?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I need to display the `UITabBarController`, but I don't need it to switch me to the Controller from the `viewControllers` array. Can I reassign the event or would it be better to create my own such `TabBarController`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a subclass for UITabBarController and confirm to `UITabBarControllerDelegate`

Then you can perform custom tab section actions in [shouldSelect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621166-tabbarcontroller) method.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, 
                  shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
{
  if viewController == secondViewController { 
   //Do your actions
   return false
  }
  return true
}
```